# ASP.NET TreeView code that works in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, firefox, treeview

The following .NET 4.0 code functions perfectly in IE9, Chrome 20 and Opera 12 but fails miserably in Firefox 13. All the browsers are default installs without plugins.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:TreeView ID="Treeview1" Runat="server" 
            onclick="javascript:postBackByObject()"
            ontreenodecheckchanged="Treeview1_TreeNodeCheckChanged" 
            ShowCheckBoxes="All" >
            <Nodes>
              <asp:TreeNode Value="Child1" Expanded="True" Text="1">
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
                <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild2" Text="B" />
             </asp:TreeNode>
               <asp:TreeNode Value="Child2" Text="2" />
               <asp:TreeNode Value="Child3" Expanded="True" Text="3">
               <asp:TreeNode Value="Grandchild1" Text="A" />
             </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
       </asp:TreeView>
       <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="156px" TextMode="MultiLine" 
            Width="295px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
 </body>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function postBackByObject() {
         var o = window.event.srcElement;
         if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
             __doPostBack("", "");
         }
     }
 </script>
 </html>
```

I am trying to catch the TreeNode checkbox events with the following code behind:

```
  protected void Treeview1_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
  {
     TextBox1.Text += e.Node.Text;
  }
```

This is quite annoying - any solution is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try handling the event more generically, so it works in both FF and other browsers.

e.g.

```
onclick="javascript:postBackByObject(event)"

function postBackByObject(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var o = evt.target || evt.srcElement; 
    if (o.tagName == "INPUT" && o.type == "checkbox") {
        __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

*edit* i forgot to add a line for target / srcElement

Comment: Many thanks Tim: the code now works perfectly on the four major browsers. Great!